# Pull name/value from other table where id is the same

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

distributors table

```
name          id
usf south     1
usf north     2
usf east      3
usf west      4
```

ogi table

```
distributor    itemname
1              cheese
1              apples
3              oranges
2              pineapples
```

I currently have the number found in column "distributor" from the "ogi table" displayed for each itemname on a page. However, I'd like to change this number to the correct distributor name, found in the "distributors table". How can I do this?

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in replacing only the query and none of the underlining programming, this may provide to be a viable solution:

```
SELECT
    ogi.itemname,
    distributors.name AS distributor
FROM
    ogi
INNER JOIN
    distributors
    ON
    ogi.distributor = distributors.id
```

Comment: This was perfect. Didn't have to modify any of my php code. Thanks for the assistance! I figured it was an inner join, but I wasn't too sure on how to accomplish it (a bit new to mysql). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    distributors a
        INNER JOIN ogi b
            ON a.id = b.distributor
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee7ef/1)

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will show you how to archive it.

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php